# Ethereum pre defined gas price in web3 wallet - is this possible?

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, metamask

Im trying to find a way to setup a fix gas price ( gwei ) in my metamask.
Probably this is not possible in metamask , but is there any way to force that or maybe there is any web3 wallet which offers that functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by this way at every transaction with web3js
contract.doSomething.sendTransaction(data, {gasPrice: web3.toWei(10, 'Gwei')}, callback...);

or I dont understand question